# IBM MQ v7.5 with JBOSS EAP 6.4 with JCA resource adapter and MDB throws 'xa_open' has failed with errorCode '-3'

Tags: java, jboss, ibm-mq, jca, resource-adapter

I am using IBM MQ v7.5 with JBOSS EAP 6.4 with JCA resource adapter and MDB.
MQ server is running in HP NonStop Integrity Server v5.3.1.12

The application is working correctly. But I am seeing the following exception in my log

```
[com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMFAIL: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.RecoveryXAResource.checkExceptions(RecoveryXAResource.java:147)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.RecoveryXAResource.recover(RecoveryXAResource.java:514)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.recover(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:185)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecoveryFirstPass(XARecoveryModule.java:541) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.29.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.17.29.Final-redhat-1]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkFirstPass(XARecoveryModule.java:181) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.29.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.17.29.Final-redhat-1]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:747) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.29.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.17.29.Final-redhat-1]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:375) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.29.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.17.29.Final-redhat-1] Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.ConfigEnvironment$1: MQJMS1068: failed to obtain XAResource.
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.ConfigEnvironment.newException(ConfigEnvironment.java:379)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQXAConnection.createXASession(MQXAConnection.java:155)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsXAConnectionImpl.createXASession(JmsXAConnectionImpl.java:125)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnection.createXASession(MQXAConnection.java:88)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.RecoveryXAResource.recover(RecoveryXAResource.java:490)
        ... 5 more Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: The method 'xa_open' has failed with errorCode '-3'.
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource.<init>(JmqiXAResource.java:274)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource.getInstance(JmqiXAResource.java:122)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.newJmqiXAResource(JmqiEnvironment.java:1598)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.base.internal.MQXAQueueManager.getXAResource(MQXAQueueManager.java:175)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQXAConnection.createXASession(MQXAConnection.java:134)
        ... 8 more
```

Can anyone help my understanding why this is happening?

Also, even if I stop my server, the connection to the MQ server was not killed. It remains as an orphan. Is it somehow related to this exception?

I am using NoTransaction in resource adapter configuration in standalone.xml

Answer (score 0):

The XA error code -3 is XAER_RMERR - which means that a problem occurred with the resource manager, in this case MQ.

Have you looked at the queue manager's error logs?

Comment: Hi Tim, queue manager's error logs had "protocol error occurred" errors.

Comment: It could be a defect. I would open a PMR with IBM to determine the cause of the failure.

Comment: I did it. Hp NonStop MQ Server doesn't support XA COnnection. Though I am not opening any XA connection, JBOSS TS manager(arjuna) is doing that. So, I stopped the XA recovery in JBOSS. Now I am not getting the error. But not yet got the root cause.

Comment: Latest Update is, an Incident report opened with RedHat regarding Jboss XA behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I missed an important point in this question (due to lack of knowledge in IBM MQ).That is, my MQ server is running in HP NonStop Integrity Server. These servers doesn't support XA connection. Hence this error.

Now, the question is how to stop it.

I have stopped the periodic recovery in JBOSS with the following properties:

> name="RecoveryEnvironmentBean.periodicRecoveryPeriod" value="0"
>   name="RecoveryEnvironmentBean.recoveryBackoffPeriod" value="0"

Comment: Please edit your original question if necessary, but do not post answers for this.

Comment: Thanks. Will edit the original question. But this is an answer. If you can find a better answer, please post (which you may not). Don't downgrade, if you don't know the answer or the context. @tvf

Answer (score -2):

This is a known issue.  IBM has issued fixpacks to address this issue.  Please see:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC97579

IBM MQ versions 7.5.0.4 and later have this fix.

And, yes, your orphaned connection is a result of this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen this post before. But I am using Implementation-Version: 7.5.0.6-p750-006-160226. And still I am getting this error. The post says, errorCode:-5 and I am getting error Code : -3. Any idea why this error is coming?

Comment: Doesn't match the error description of the APAR, so not a match